# prolog recursive searching with contraints

Tags: search, prolog, transitive-closure

I have a house with rooms that are defined with connections for when you can go from one room to another eg.

```
connection(garage,sidehall).
connection(sidehall,kitchen).
connection(kitchen,diningroom).

canget(X,Y):-connection(X,Y).
canget(X,Y):-connection(X,_),
            write('player goes from '),write(X),write(' to     '),write(Y),nl,
            canget(_,Y).
```

Im trying to figure out how make it so the player can only get from one room to another when they have a specific item, such as you can only be in the kitchen when items = gloves.

```
canget(X,Y,Item):-connection(X,Y,Item),canbein(Y,Item).
canget(X,Y,Item):-connection(X,Somewhere,Item),canbein(Somewhere,Item),canget(Somewhere,Y,Item).
```

tried defining canbein with:

```
canbein(kitchen):- item(sword).
canbein(sidehall):- item(hat).
```

but that doesnt work!

Have defined my items as such, not sure if this is right either:

```
item(gloves,sword,helm,cheese).
```

Basically, have i declared my item values correctly?
How can i use the specific item value to make canget x to y false?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see a few problems with your code. Firstly, you call `canbein` with two arguments (from `canget` predicate). However, `canbein` is defined as single-argument predicate. Therefore, the call always fails as no  `canbein/2` predicate exists.

I suggest the following modification:

```
canbein(kitchen, sword).
canbein(sidehall, hat).
```

Than, the item definition is not required. Let's think about what happens during the unification of

```
canget(X,Y,Item) :- connection(X,Y,Item), canbein(Y,Item).
```

Let's assume the following setting `X=sidehall, Y=kitchen, Item==sword`. This predicate should be OK. Assuming the `conection` predicate is OK, prolog tries to find `canbein(Y, Item)` i.e. `canbein(kitchen, sword)` and it succeeds.

On the contrary, if the Item is different the unification fails, hence it works as expected.

The second problem is the `item` predicate. By your definition, it expects 4 arguments. That's nonsense, of course. You should declare it like

```
item(gloves).
item(sword).
item(helm).
item(cheese).
```

However, I don't think this predicate is necessary at all. Just to be clear, try to call `item(X)` and obtain all results (the four declared). Try it with the prior definition - what should you even ask for?

I hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks so much mate, appreciate it. think i understand it a bit better now :) i suck it programming!

Comment: @JJ1 Please consider marking the answer if the it helped you :) it's a good common at stackoverflow since the other users will know that it solves the problem. You can vote it up if you like the style etc.